# How to implement aws ses SendRawEmail with attachment in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

I need to implement Amazon ses SendRawEmail with attachment in golang,
i tried with the following code :

```
session, err := session.NewSession()
svc := ses.New(session, &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")})

source := aws.String("XXX <xxx@xxx.com>")
destinations := []*string{aws.String("xxx <xxx@xxx.com>")}
message := ses.RawMessage{ Data: []byte(` From: xxx <xxx@xxx.com>\\nTo: xxx  <xxx@xxx.com>\\nSubject: Test email (contains an attachment)\\nMIME-Version: 1.0\\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\\n\\n--NextPart\\nContent-Type: text/plain\\n\\nThis is the message body.\\n\\n--NextPart\\nContent-Type: text/plain;\\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"sample.txt\"\\n\\nThis is the text in the attachment.\\n\\n--NextPart--" `)}
input := ses.SendRawEmailInput{Source: source, Destinations: destinations, RawMessage: &message}
output, err := svc.SendRawEmail(&input)
```

but in the mail I receive, it shows the content which I have given in the message, instead of the attachment. Not sure what exactly is wrong???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refer to [AWS example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ses/#example_SES_SendRawEmail_shared00) for Sending RAW email with attachment.

Implementation Suggestion: for an easy to compose email and get email as bytes and send it to SES as mentioned in the above reference example.

Use library `gopkg.in/gomail.v2` to compose your email message with attachment and then call [WriteTo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.WriteTo) method.

```
var emailRaw bytes.Buffer
emailMessage.WriteTo(&emailRaw)

// while create instance of RawMessage
RawMessage: &ses.RawMessage{
    Data: emailRaw.Bytes(),
}
```

Good luck!

---

**EDIT:** For the comment.

Compose the email-

```
msg := gomail.NewMessage()
msg.SetHeader("From", "alex@example.com")
msg.SetHeader("To", "bob@example.com", "cora@example.com")
msg.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
msg.SetBody("text/html", "Hello <b>Bob</b> and <i>Cora</i>!")
msg.Attach("/home/Alex/lolcat.jpg")

var emailRaw bytes.Buffer
msg.WriteTo(&emailRaw)

message := ses.RawMessage{ Data: emailRaw.Bytes() }

// Remaining is same as what you mentioned the question.
```

Comment: `ses.RawMessage.Data` value is not a valid email with attachment. I have updated the answer with email example.

Comment: Maybe `msg.WriteTo(emailRaw)` should be  `msg.WriteTo(&emailRaw)`

Comment: @brunetto Thanks for catching typo issue. I have updated the code snippet.

Comment: @jeevatkm that AWS example is actually incorrect; newlines shouldn't be escaped before converting the raw message to bytes (just verified this right now via calls to SES).

Comment: @yangmillstheory Sorry for the delayed response. In the above example new line is not handled explicitly. Could you please point out which line it is or you could help to update the above code snippet. thanks.

Comment: @jeevatkm Shared attachment is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to attach a file from bytes:

```
msg.Attach("report.pdf", gomail.SetCopyFunc(func(w io.Writer) error {
    _, err := w.Write(reportData)
    return err
}))
```